# How to register Azure Onpremise Data Gateway in a specific subscription

Tags: azure

When Installing Azure Data Gateway, I need to sign-in with an account to register the Azure Data Gateway within the Azure Subscription. Normally, this works great. But now I have access to multiple subscriptions (multiple customers). When I sign in, I cannot choose a specific tenant/subscription. It always registers the gateway in my own tenant.
Any idea's on how to get this done?

I've tried:

1. Delete Chrome signin information
2. Delete accounts in Credential Manager
3. first login with az login + az set-subscription

More information about the Azure Onpremise Data Gateway
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-gateway-install#install-data-gateway

Answer (score 0):

It's written in prerequisites that your account must belongs to single AD or directory.
[image]

I would suggest for life long perspective ask your client to create a service account and register data gateway with that service account.

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept this as answer if you found this is useful.